# How to check if a char in the string is '?

Tags: java, string, csv, char

I'm trying to implement a CSV parser. Suppose I have an input string `"a, a'b, c, d'c, b"`, and output should be a list of strings: `"a"`, `"a'b, c, d'c"`, `"b"`. So basically it means all chars between `''`should be a part of one string. The problem I am facing is that when I scan the input string, I cannot check if the char is `'`, because `if(c==''')` is invalid, because `'`is an invalid character constant. So how should I check if a char in the input string is `'`?

Comment: genarally special characters need to be escaped with a \ in front of them

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the special character `'` with a `\`. Take a look at the [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) documentation for more information.

`b` should be equal to `true` after executing this:

```
Character charValue = '\'';
boolean b = (charValue == '\'');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source library that already does this called [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).  You can use it directly or get the code from [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/).